# Weird Date issue with Hibernate in Karaf OSGI server

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, osgi, apache-karaf

We are in the middle of a project to upgrade our OSGi Server application from:

- Karaf 2.3.1
- OSGi Core 4.3.0
- Hibernate 3.4.0 GA
- Spring (including SpringDM) 3.2.2.RELEASE
- c3p0 connection pooling 0.9.1.2
- PostgreSQL Driver 9.1.901

To:

- Karaf 4.0.5
- OSGi Core 6.0.0
- Hibernate 5.0.9.Final
- Hikari connection pooling 2.4.3
- PostgreSQL Driver 9.4-1204-jdbc42

The new version uses Declarative Services instead of Spring DM.

After conversion we started getting problems retrieving Dates from the Database. Any date which contains the date of the Daylight Saving changeover here in NZ this year (25th September) gets inconsistent results. The first 5 times we query this date **after the server has started**, the date is correct. However, after that it changes to be the date before. That is, if the database contains '2016-09-25', it returns '2016-09-24'.

Initially we thought it was a JPA Entity population issue, but we have now narrowed it down to a very simple Native Query:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT DATE '2016-09-25'").getResultList()
```

which returns a Date object with the 25th, time 00:00 the first few times, then it returns a Date object with the 24th, time 11:00 thereafter.

The weird thing is if we add the time, like this:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT DATE '2016-09-25 00:00:00'").getResultList()
```

then we always get a Date object with the 25th, time 00:00.

What we've tried:

- Basic test program which does simple JDBC query - works OK every time
- Hibernate Entity manager outside of Karaf - works OK every time
- Dates other than 2016-09-25 - works OK every time

I can understand that either applying Daylight Savings or not would result in one of these Date values. What I cannot understand is why it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like karaf sets some "environment" variable differently than you have outside of karaf. I am not sure what exactly it may be. I suggest to also ask this on the hibernate list.

Comment: Sorry Christian, the Karaf thing was a red herring in the end. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the PostgreSQL driver after all. See [this discussion on the pgjdbc github site](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/130). It is related to this configuration setting:

> - `prepareThreshold = int`
>
> Determine the number of PreparedStatement executions required before switching over to use server side prepared statements. The default is five, meaning start using server side prepared statements on the fifth execution of the same PreparedStatement object.

If I understand the discussion correctly, after the prepare threshold has been reached for the number of times that the same prepared statement is executed, Postgres switches to using binary prepared statements on the server, and these have the incorrect timezone.

See also the "[Server Prepared Statements](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/server-prepare.html)" section in the PostgreSQL JDBC documentation.

There were a few Red Herrings in our tests. The problem only manifests itself when using prepared statements, which is why our tests outside Karaf were OK as we didn't use prepared statements in those tests, and Hibernate always uses prepared statments.

The problem existed until at least version 9.4-1204-jdb42 (the version we were using), however in version 9.4.1208 the problem no longer exists. We have upgraded to this driver version and the problem has gone away. Our original server used version 9.1 which also did not have the problem.